# I have a problem creating a user using the firebase, FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I did the authentication, but when I click to create an account it throws an error:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

[image]

```
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void _submitAuthForm(String email, String user, String pass, bool isLogin , context) async  {
    AuthResult authResult;
    try {
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: pass);
      } else {
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: pass);
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      var errorMessage = 'An error ocurred. Please check your credentials.';
      if (err.message != null) {
        errorMessage = err.message!;
      }

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Text(errorMessage),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **enabled Sign-in with Email/Password** in Firebase Console.
Also, try **updating packages to the latest version**. Along with that do **upgrade your flutter version** as well.
Once you did all that, try running **flutter clean** and re-running your project.
Cheers!! Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. stop the app
   [image]
2. run the app again

---

Hope it helps!